# MVC# view to pdf having CSS and form elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, itext

I want to convert a **MVC3 view of a from filled by user to pdf**. When a user click a button, a PDF should be opened on a new tab of browser instead of view. The view has internal CSS and checkbox so that user can check a checkbox in the pdf and can then take a print.

Following is the view to be opened in pdf through action result

```
@using Project.Models
@model Student
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
background-color:#d0e4fe;
}
/*and other CSS*/
</style>
 <script>
//script to check /uncheck checkbox
</script>
</head>
<body>

/* Information of Student through model */  

CheckList
<input type="checkbox" name="card1" value="Passport">Passoprt
<input type="checkbox" name="card2" value="Voter">Voter Card
<input type="checkbox" name="card3" value="ID">College id

</html>
```

I am using itextsharp library and I want to avoid others packages like razorpdf.

How can this be achieved ??

Comment: Have you tried [XMLWorker](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/) ?

Comment: no.. I have tired to use HtmlWorker, but its not giving the desired results.

Comment: HTMLWorker is deprecated and not supported anymore. It's been replaced by XMLWorker.

Comment: Okie .. Can u please write a action method for the above using XMLWriter.. I mean the steps i should follow..

Comment: if you are using htmlworker so stylye tag not working remove style tag and then create pdf.use inline stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the input string of checkbox tag as "u0261" which is the unicode for check box will solve the problem